# how can i solve this problem without create a new project?

Tags: kotlin

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

I try to upgrade the Gradle, but nothing will change.

Answer (score 1):

It actually says what to do.

Just change `compileSdkVersion` from `32` to `33` in `build.gradle`.